# How to uncheck only one checkbox in list of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of products that will get checked if I click select all. What I want to do is when all the checkboxes are checked and I uncheck just one checkbox, it should only uncheck the clicked element not all of the elements.

```
$('#selectAll').change(function () {
    $('#pfilters  li  input').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: On each change event retrieve the number of checked checkboxes. If it's the same as the total number of boxes, select the 'check all' box, if no deselect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like that?

```js
$('#selectAll').change(function () {
    $('#pfilters  li  input').prop('checked', this.checked);
});


function isAllSelected() {
  return $('#pfilters  li  input').length ===  $('#pfilters  li  input:checked').length;
}
$('#pfilters  li  input').on('change', function() {
  $('#selectAll').prop('checked', isAllSelected());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"/>Select All</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="pfilters">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox">Select Product 1</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox">Select Product 2</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox">Select Product 3</label></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```